# Excel Options for Changing Font

Tags: microsoft-excel, fonts

I've had this problem in Excel 2014 and 2016.

When I go into File, Options, General and change the font, Excel prompts me to restart the program to keep the new font, but when I restart, Excel shows the font I'm trying to change.  How can I make the font stay and automatically apply when I open a new spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

This problem unfortunately has persisted for years, without a plausible reason.

My advice is to set a default sheet as you want, save it as Excel template and then use it every time you need to create a new file.